# Is the same ZooKeeper ensemble supposed to be used by different products?

Tags: solr, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to estimate my Cloud architecture design and costs where I have multiple products (Solr & Kafka) that need to use ZooKeeper.  Is it best to have each of them on the same ZooKeeper ensemble or should a new ensemble be created for each product?  If the later... wow, that will require a lot of servers! :)  Can I run multiple ZooKeepers on the same 3 hosts in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may share the same Zookeeper ensemble between Solr and Kafka. Solr and Kafka don't add a lot of data to Zookeeper and it will okay if you share the same ensemble between them.
You may run multiple Zookeepers on the same 3 hosts or you may host multiple Zookeeper ensemble in the same 3 hosts. But that won't benefit you much.